# Really struggling with CONCAT_WS ... please help a newbie :)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, concatenation

PHP and MYSQL newbie here.....can really use your help right now. I implemented a Submodal into my script, and finally got it to submit "User Notes" into the database. Unfortunately with each new submission, the text that is submitted overwrites the previous submission. I was told to use CONCAT_WS to prevent that from happening...I have been trying for several hours on Dreamweaver to accomplish that but it's not working. Here is my code for that section...

New code with this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'great'')
WHERE Id=35' at line 1
```

Code...

```
 <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/cms.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) { 
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
 }

 $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) :      
 mysql_escape_string($theValue);
 switch ($theType) {
  case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
 case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
 case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
 case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
 return $theValue;
}
}

 $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
 $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "lead_note_form")) {
 $updateSQL = sprintf ("UPDATE Leads SET Notes = CONCAT_WS('\n', notes, '%s') WHERE Id=%d",
 GetSQLValueString($_POST['note'], "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($_POST['Id'], "int"));

 mysql_select_db($database_cms, $cms);
 $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $cms) or die(mysql_error());

 $updateGoTo = "test6.php";
 if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
 $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
 $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 }
 header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
(isset($_GET['Id'])) {
$colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['Id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_cms, $cms);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT Id, First_Name, Last_Name, Notes FROM Leads WHERE Id = %s",    
GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "int"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $cms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
```

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function clickSubmit() {
$("form").submit();
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<table><tr><td>

<div id="lead_box">
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="lead_note_form" id="lead_note_form"
target="_top">   

<input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Id']; ?>" />
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#eeeeee"><p align="center" class="name"></p></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><textarea rows="15" style="width: 99%" readonly><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Notes']; ?> 
</textarea></td>  
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top"><p class="title">Add Note:</p></td>
 <tr>
   <td>
    <textarea name="note" id="note" style="width: 99%" rows="5"></textarea>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="lead_note_form" />
</form>
</div><!-- and of lead box -->
</td></tr>
 <tr><td>
<div align="right">
<input  type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save" onClick="clickSubmit()"/>
<input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="window.parent.hidePopWin()"/>
</div>
</td></tr></table>



</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing I can see is your `sprintf()` has two substitution parameters but only one placeholder. I'm thinking you actually meant

```
$updateSQL = sprintf ("UPDATE Leads SET Notes = CONCAT_WS('\n', Notes, %s) WHERE Id=%d",
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['note'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['Id'], "int"));
```

Also, your `GetSQLValueString()` function automatically wraps "text" parameters with quotes, so you need to removes the quotes around the placeholders.

I also changed the ID placeholder to `%d` as I assume you're expecting a number.

You may benefit from enabling error reporting for development. This error (and potentially another regarding the undefined `$Notes` variable) would have made debugging easier.

Place this at the top of your script (for development only)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

### Personal Crusade

Drop the MySQL library and move your code to PDO, you won't look back.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE Leads SET Notes = CONCAT_WS(:sep, Notes, :note) WHERE Id = :id');
$stmt->execute(array(
    'sep'  => PHP_EOL,
    'note' => $_POST['note'],
    'id'   => $_POST['Id']
));
```

### A Better Approach

Consider storing each note entry in a separate table with a foreign key relationship to the parent "Lead" and creation timestamp. That way, you simply retrieve all the child note entries in creation order and new entries are simply inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE LeadNotes (
    id         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    lead_id    INT,
    note       TEXT,
    created_dt TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (lead_id) REFERENCES Leads (Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! What I am trying to do is, to use the submodal to pop up when the "notes" image is clicked, I have it working to the point where I can submit data from it, and also view it from it's top portion.  The way it's supposed to work is the top portion should retrieve previous notes from mysql.  The problem I am having is that when I submit the text to the DB, it stores it, and then overwrites the last submission with the new one....sorry hope that was not too confusing...I also tried the code, and when my submodal pops up I get the original note submitted, and "NULL"..

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer with what I think would be a better approach

Comment: Do you think thats a better approach?  We have a lot of clients, and there will be a lot of notes inputted...I tried the previous code and this is what it gave me..Notice: Undefined variable: db in /home/content/02/8116402/html/test5.php on line 46

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/content/02/8116402/html/test5.php on line 46  .... Thanks for your help and patience, I have been struggling with this all day!

Comment: @Alex In that case, I think this is something you **have** to do. I also suggest you read the [PDO book](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) in the PHP manual. My code was just an example as a replacement for what you already had

Comment: Ok, I will definitely do that.  Thank you! Would you have any idea what this error means, when I inputted your initial code, it worked in a way, but the only things that are storing are "NULL" they are stacking up on top of eachother which is what I want, and its bringing it back to my submodal... but it's just "NULL" ... and this is an error code that I get:

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Notes in /home/content/02/8116402/html/test5.php on line 47

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/02/8116402/html/test5.php:47) in /home/content/02/8116402/html/test5.php on line 58

Comment: @Alex There is no `'Notes'` entry in the `$_POST` array. What is your form field name?

Comment: The form field is Notes....I just posted the code in the question, ill post the code of the form also, chances are good that the mistake is there also...sorry about that..

Comment: @Alex Your textarea name is `note`, not `Notes`

Comment: Phil, the first revision did the same thing, it updates the db but with NULL, and it brings NULL back into the form....the second way did not work, gave me error msgs......

Comment: @Alex Sorry, not following you. Update your question with what you're attempting

Comment: Sorry about that...The goal is to retrieve the notes into the submodal so the user is able to view the history, and also submit and save new notes on top of the old ones (through the same submodal).  You got me one step further, but only now what's showing when I save and retrieve is "NULL" instead of the actual notes that I submit..

Comment: @Alex Did you change `$_POST['Notes']` to `$_POST['note']` as indicated above? I've updated my answer with the new information

Comment: Yes I did...It is not changing, keeps putting out NULL

Comment: I did the error reporting on the top of my script as you suggested and this is the error that I get: Notice: Undefined index: Note in /home/content/02/8116402/html/test5.php on line 45

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/02/8116402/html/test5.php:45) in /home/content/02/8116402/html/test5.php on line 56

Comment: @Alex There's a distinct difference between `Note` and `note`. To spell it out, your form field is "note", **all lowercase** whereas you are trying to use `$_POST['Note']` with a **capital "N"**. Like I said before, update your question with any new code you try that continues to not work as expected. Then, I (or anyone else on this site) could see and point out these errors.

Comment: sorry, new to this site, will post code from the question from now on. I just posted the entire thing, with the new error, and I changed the "Note" to "note."  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Alex Your `GetSQLValueString()` function is quoting strings already so the quotes in your SQL are redundant, causing an error. I've updated my answer

Comment: I hope I posted it the right way this time, if not, please explain how exactly to do it.  You are great, thanks for the patience and your help! My only question is, how can I add a time or date stamp, or both, and also add an extra line of space when the notes get submitted.  Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @Alex No, you didn't. a) The question title is not the place to leave comments to specific users. b) Don't ask new questions in comments. Who's going to see it way down here? If this one is solved, accept an answer and create a new question.

Comment: +1 for mentioning PDO (and particularly prepared statements).  I so wish more people would.