# Need help with CONCAT_WS

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

```
Notice: Undefined variable: note in /home/content/02/8116402/html/test5.php on line 48

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at    
/home/content/02/8116402/html/lock.php:16) in /home/content/02/8116402/html/test5.php on line 61

<?php
include('lock.php');
?>
<?php echo $login_session; ?>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/cms.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
 if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

 $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) :   
 mysql_escape_string($theValue);

 switch ($theType) {
 case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
 case "long":
 case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
 case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
 case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
 case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
 return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
```

---------- CODE IN QUESTION

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "lead_note_form")) {
 $note = date("m/d/y H:i:s")." - ".$_SESSION['username']. '\n' . $note. '\n'; 
 $updateSQL = sprintf ("UPDATE Leads SET Notes = CONCAT_WS('\n', Notes, %s) WHERE Id=%d",
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['note'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['Id'], "int"));
```

----------CODE IN QUESTION

```
  mysql_select_db($database_cms, $cms);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $cms) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "test6.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
  $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Id'])) {
$colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['Id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_cms, $cms);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT Id, First_Name, Last_Name, Notes FROM Leads WHERE Id = %s",     
GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "int"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $cms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function clickSubmit() {
$("form").submit();

</script>

</head>

<body>

<table><tr><td>

<div id="lead_box">
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="lead_note_form" id="lead_note_form"     

 target="_top">


<input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Id']; ?>" />
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#eeeeee"><p align="center" class="name"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea rows="15" style="width: 99%" readonly><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Notes']; ?></textarea>       
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td valign="top"><p class="title">Add Note:</p></td>
 <tr>
 <td>
    <textarea name="note" id="note" style="width: 99%" rows="5"></textarea>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="lead_note_form" />
 </form>
 </div><!-- and of lead box -->
</td></tr>
 <tr><td>
<div align="right">
<input  type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save" onClick="clickSubmit()"/> 
<input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="window.parent.hidePopWin()"/>
</div>
</td></tr></table>



</body>
</html>
<?php
 mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
<?
```

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6906574/283366

Comment: What "date/time"? Show your output code too

Comment: Would you mind formulating a question as well?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't check all very well. So please just ignore it if my answer is not what you need.

Your variable `$note` is not defined before. Normally this is not a problem in php. But if you want to receive notices from php then those notices will be sent as a header information. Right now you are getting one of them. The warning after that is about the headers because you are sending another header information after the Notice.

I guess there are 2 different ways;

1- Define all your variables carefully before assigning any value to them.
2- Close the notice messages from your php settings.